# Java8 -Optional.orElseGet with Supplier defined inside () vs in method call

Tags: java-8, option-type

As per the documentation the difference between

orElse and orElseGet is in the fact that in the case of orElseGet(x) the x part

is called incase Optional.isPresent is false

But in below program in case the supplier x is a another method call  in orElseGet(x)

the x part is called even if Optional.isPresent is true similiar to the behavior of

orElse(). Why is the behavior of orElseGet() in this scenario same as orElse()?

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class TestOrElseGet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         
        checkOrElseGet();
    }

    private static void checkOrElseGet() {
        System.out.println("------Start Optional.orElseGet-------");

        String first= getFirst();

        //  else part is not initialized 

        // else  doesn't get initialized if its inside OrElseGet()
        String  myOptional = Optional.of(first).orElseGet(() -> {
            System.out.println("OrElseGet - Create & Return Second");            
            return "Second";
        });

        System.out.println(
                "Result of OrElseGet  " + myOptional);

        //  if supplier is a method then its gets called 

        myOptional = Optional.of(getThird()).orElseGet(getNumberFromSupplier());

        System.out.println(" Result of OrElseGet is "
                + myOptional);
 
        

        Optional<String> empty = Optional.empty();
        // OrElseGet - else is initialized as optional was empty
        myOptional = empty.orElseGet(() -> {
            System.out.println("OrElseGet - Create & Return Fourth"); 
            return "Four" ;
        });

        System.out.println("Result of OrElseGEt is " + myOptional);

        System.out.println("----------Completed-----------");
    }

    private static Supplier<String> getNumberFromSupplier() {
        System.out.println("Inside Supplier call..");
        return ()->{ 
            return "Supplying TEN";
        };
    }

    private static String getThird() {
        System.out.println("Inside Third");
        return "Third";
    }

    private static String getFirst() {
        System.out.println("Inside GetFirst");
        return "First";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contract of `orElseGet(Supplier)` says the →`Supplier`← will only be invoked if the value is not present. More specifically, it's the `Supplier#get()` method that's lazily invoked (on the `Supplier` instance passed to `orElseGet`).

And your code shows that. However, this bit:

> ```java
> private static Supplier<String> getNumberFromSupplier() {
>     System.out.println("Inside Supplier call..");
>     return ()->{ 
>         return "Supplying TEN";
>     };
> }
> ```

Indicates a misunderstanding. Your `println` log says "Inside Supplier call...", but at that point you *are not inside the supplier*. The `Supplier` is the lambda expression and is returned from the method. That said, you're correct that the `getNumberFromSupplier` method is invoked eagerly, but that's because its return value is passed as an argument to the `orElseGet` call. Even for `orElseGet(() -> ... )` the `Supplier` is created eagerly for the same reason.

If you had the following:

```java
private static Supplier<String> getNumberFromSupplier() {
    // Remember, the lambda is the implementation of Supplier#get()
    return () -> {
        System.out.println("Inside Supplier call...");
        return "Supplying TEN";
    };
}
```

Then you'd see the `Supplier` is lazily invoked. Notice the new location for the `println` call. Additionally, the method would be better named `getNumberSupplier` as that's a more apt description of what the method actually does.

Comment: Thanks Slaw for the detailed answer , has clarified the doubt.